# Limiting WCF service to response just to one domain requests?

Tags: c#, wcf, security

I created a WCF service and hosted it on the Internet.
I wanna consume it from `somename1.com` and some static IPs.
Can we say to WCF to just response to requests from `somename1.com` domain (or multiple specific domains) or from some static IPs

**Edit:**
What about the following config from http://forums.asp.net/t/1598209.aspx:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IMyTestService">
  <identity>
    <dns value="ip address or domain name" />
  </identity>
</endpoint>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be done by having your service endpoint use a [Message Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

[Here is a in depth Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37280/WCF-Service-Behavior-Example-IPFilter-Allow-Deny-A) that goes step by step how to make a IP filter in WCF. Here is a example of it in use once you write the IPFilter class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- Example configuration -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="IPFilter" 
    type="IPFilter.Configuration.IPFilterConfiguration,IPFilter"/>
  </configSections>

  <IPFilter>
    <HttpModule FilterName="Default" />
    <Filters>
      <add Name="Default" DefaultBehavior="Deny">
        <deny hosts="192.168.11.12,192.168.1.*" />
        <allow hosts="192.168.0.0/16" />
        <deny hosts="*" />
      </add>

    </Filters>
  </IPFilter>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what's the meaning of `16` at the end of `192.168.0.0/16`?

Comment: @Mohammad - the /16 is the range or block of IPs

Comment: Please re-read my answer, the config will not work by itself. you have to write the IPFilter class too, the linked tutorial shows how to do it.